# libvirtd Error: Could not access KVM kernel module: Is a directory

Tags: centos7, kvm, libvirt

Has anyone else come across this error before?
Google yields no results and I'm baffled by the error message telling me the KVM kernel module is a directory.

virt-install output in debug mode:

```
[Wed, 26 Oct 2016 16:12:37 virt-install 6220] DEBUG (cli:246) Launched with command line: /usr/share/virt-manager/virt-install --name test --ram 4096 --disk path=/kvms/test.img,size=20 --vcpus 2 --os-type linux --os-variant rhel7 --network bridge=br0 --graphics none --console pty,target_type=serial --cdrom /isos/CentOS-7-x86_64-NetInstall-1511.iso --graphics vnc,listen=0.0.0.0,password=pass123 --noautoconsole --debug
[Wed, 26 Oct 2016 16:12:37 virt-install 6220] DEBUG (cli:256) Requesting libvirt URI default
[Wed, 26 Oct 2016 16:12:37 virt-install 6220] DEBUG (cli:260) Received libvirt URI qemu:///system
[Wed, 26 Oct 2016 16:12:37 virt-install 6220] DEBUG (virt-install:357) Requesting virt method 'default', hv type 'default'.
[Wed, 26 Oct 2016 16:12:37 virt-install 6220] DEBUG (virt-install:591) Received virt method 'kvm'
[Wed, 26 Oct 2016 16:12:37 virt-install 6220] DEBUG (virt-install:592) Hypervisor name is 'hvm'
[Wed, 26 Oct 2016 16:12:37 virt-install 6220] DEBUG (virt-install:269) Distilled --network options: ['bridge=br0']
[Wed, 26 Oct 2016 16:12:37 virt-install 6220] DEBUG (virt-install:182) Distilled --disk options: ['path=/kvms/test.img,size=20']
[Wed, 26 Oct 2016 16:12:38 virt-install 6220] DEBUG (devicedisk:425) Creating volume 'test.img' on pool 'kvms'
[Wed, 26 Oct 2016 16:12:38 virt-install 6220] DEBUG (devicedisk:546) disk.set_vol_install: name=test.img poolxml=
<pool type='dir'>
  <name>kvms</name>
  <uuid>ea30045f-1970-4da1-bbf4-6bf739bc2cc7</uuid>
  <capacity unit='bytes'>2927812804608</capacity>
  <allocation unit='bytes'>469499904</allocation>
  <available unit='bytes'>2927343304704</available>
  <source>
  </source>
  <target>
    <path>/kvms</path>
    <permissions>
      <mode>0755</mode>
      <owner>107</owner>
      <group>107</group>
      <label>system_u:object_r:fusefs_t:s0</label>
    </permissions>
  </target>
</pool>

[Wed, 26 Oct 2016 16:12:38 virt-install 6220] DEBUG (guest:238) Setting Guest.os_variant to 'rhel7'
[Wed, 26 Oct 2016 16:12:38 virt-install 6220] DEBUG (virt-install:746) Guest.has_install_phase: True

Starting install...
[Wed, 26 Oct 2016 16:12:38 virt-install 6220] DEBUG (storage:765) Creating storage volume 'test.img' with xml:
<volume>
  <name>test.img</name>
  <capacity>21474836480</capacity>
  <allocation>21474836480</allocation>
  <target>
    <format type="qcow2"/>
    <features>
      <lazy_refcounts/>
    </features>
  </target>
</volume>

[Wed, 26 Oct 2016 16:12:38 virt-install 6220] DEBUG (storage:798) Using vol create flags=1
Allocating 'test.img'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    |  20 GB  00:00:00     
[Wed, 26 Oct 2016 16:12:39 virt-install 6220] DEBUG (storage:805) Storage volume 'test.img' install complete.
[Wed, 26 Oct 2016 16:12:39 virt-install 6220] DEBUG (guest:463) Generated install XML: 
<domain type="kvm">
  <name>test</name>
  <uuid>05e708e1-4d0b-44b6-8ab8-52e5f0ed937b</uuid>
  <memory>4194304</memory>
  <currentMemory>4194304</currentMemory>
  <vcpu>2</vcpu>
  <os>
    <type arch="x86_64">hvm</type>
    <boot dev="cdrom"/>
    <boot dev="hd"/>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
    <apic/>
  </features>
  <cpu mode="custom" match="exact">
    <model>Haswell-noTSX</model>
  </cpu>
  <clock offset="utc">
    <timer name="rtc" tickpolicy="catchup"/>
    <timer name="pit" tickpolicy="delay"/>
    <timer name="hpet" present="no"/>
  </clock>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>destroy</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>destroy</on_crash>
  <pm>
    <suspend-to-mem enabled="no"/>
    <suspend-to-disk enabled="no"/>
  </pm>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/libexec/qemu-kvm</emulator>
    <disk type="file" device="disk">
      <driver name="qemu" type="qcow2"/>
      <source file="/kvms/test.img"/>
      <target dev="vda" bus="virtio"/>
    </disk>
    <disk type="file" device="cdrom">
      <driver name="qemu" type="raw"/>
      <source file="/isos/CentOS-7-x86_64-NetInstall-1511.iso"/>
      <target dev="hda" bus="ide"/>
      <readonly/>
    </disk>
    <controller type="usb" index="0" model="ich9-ehci1"/>
    <controller type="usb" index="0" model="ich9-uhci1">
      <master startport="0"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="usb" index="0" model="ich9-uhci2">
      <master startport="2"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="usb" index="0" model="ich9-uhci3">
      <master startport="4"/>
    </controller>
    <interface type="bridge">
      <source bridge="br0"/>
      <mac address="52:54:00:de:72:85"/>
      <model type="virtio"/>
    </interface>
    <input type="tablet" bus="usb"/>
    <graphics type="vnc" port="-1" listen="0.0.0.0" passwd="RibEymtU"/>
    <console type="pty">
      <target type="serial"/>
    </console>
    <channel type="unix">
      <source mode="bind"/>
      <target type="virtio" name="org.qemu.guest_agent.0"/>
    </channel>
  </devices>
</domain>

[Wed, 26 Oct 2016 16:12:39 virt-install 6220] DEBUG (guest:464) Generated boot XML: 
<domain type="kvm">
  <name>test</name>
  <uuid>05e708e1-4d0b-44b6-8ab8-52e5f0ed937b</uuid>
  <memory>4194304</memory>
  <currentMemory>4194304</currentMemory>
  <vcpu>2</vcpu>
  <os>
    <type arch="x86_64">hvm</type>
    <boot dev="hd"/>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
    <apic/>
  </features>
  <cpu mode="custom" match="exact">
    <model>Haswell-noTSX</model>
  </cpu>
  <clock offset="utc">
    <timer name="rtc" tickpolicy="catchup"/>
    <timer name="pit" tickpolicy="delay"/>
    <timer name="hpet" present="no"/>
  </clock>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>restart</on_crash>
  <pm>
    <suspend-to-mem enabled="no"/>
    <suspend-to-disk enabled="no"/>
  </pm>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/libexec/qemu-kvm</emulator>
    <disk type="file" device="disk">
      <driver name="qemu" type="qcow2"/>
      <source file="/kvms/test.img"/>
      <target dev="vda" bus="virtio"/>
    </disk>
    <disk type="block" device="cdrom">
      <target dev="hda" bus="ide"/>
      <readonly/>
    </disk>
    <controller type="usb" index="0" model="ich9-ehci1"/>
    <controller type="usb" index="0" model="ich9-uhci1">
      <master startport="0"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="usb" index="0" model="ich9-uhci2">
      <master startport="2"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="usb" index="0" model="ich9-uhci3">
      <master startport="4"/>
    </controller>
    <interface type="bridge">
      <source bridge="br0"/>
      <mac address="52:54:00:de:72:85"/>
      <model type="virtio"/>
    </interface>
    <input type="tablet" bus="usb"/>
    <graphics type="vnc" port="-1" listen="0.0.0.0" passwd="RibEymtU"/>
    <console type="pty">
      <target type="serial"/>
    </console>
    <channel type="unix">
      <source mode="bind"/>
      <target type="virtio" name="org.qemu.guest_agent.0"/>
    </channel>
  </devices>
</domain>

[Wed, 26 Oct 2016 16:12:40 virt-install 6220] DEBUG (cli:295)   File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virt-install", line 1084, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virt-install", line 1078, in main
    start_install(guest, continue_inst, options)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virt-install", line 784, in start_install
    fail(e, do_exit=False)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/cli.py", line 295, in fail
    logging.debug("".join(traceback.format_stack()))

[Wed, 26 Oct 2016 16:12:40 virt-install 6220] ERROR (cli:296) internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: Could not access KVM kernel module: Is a directory
failed to initialize KVM: Is a directory

[Wed, 26 Oct 2016 16:12:40 virt-install 6220] DEBUG (cli:298) 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virt-install", line 755, in start_install
    dom = guest.start_install(meter=meter, noboot=options.noreboot)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/guest.py", line 417, in start_install
    noboot)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/guest.py", line 481, in _create_guest
    dom = self.conn.createLinux(start_xml or final_xml, 0)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/libvirt.py", line 3585, in createLinux
    if ret is None:raise libvirtError('virDomainCreateLinux() failed', conn=self)
libvirtError: internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: Could not access KVM kernel module: Is a directory
failed to initialize KVM: Is a directory

[Wed, 26 Oct 2016 16:12:40 virt-install 6220] DEBUG (cli:309) Domain installation does not appear to have been successful.
If it was, you can restart your domain by running:
  virsh --connect qemu:///system start test
otherwise, please restart your installation.
Domain installation does not appear to have been successful.
If it was, you can restart your domain by running:
  virsh --connect qemu:///system start test
otherwise, please restart your installation.
```

/var/log/libvirtd/qemu/template-01a.img output:

```
2016-10-26 15:08:35.182+0000: starting up libvirt version: 1.2.17, package: 13.el7_2.5 (CentOS BuildSystem <http://bugs.centos.org>, 2016-06-23-14:23:27, worker1.bsys.centos.org), qemu version: 1.5.3 (qemu-kvm-1.5.3-105.el7_2.7)
LC_ALL=C PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin QEMU_AUDIO_DRV=none /usr/libexec/qemu-kvm -name template-01 -S -machine pc-i440fx-rhel7.0.0,accel=kvm,usb=off -cpu Haswell,-rtm,-hle -m 4096 -realtime mlock=off -smp 4,sockets=4,cores=1,threads=1 -uuid d98fb7e2-9c58-43f3-b94b-f73c76d9714b -no-user-config -nodefaults -chardev socket,id=charmonitor,path=/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/domain-template-01/monitor.sock,server,nowait -mon chardev=charmonitor,id=monitor,mode=control -rtc base=utc,driftfix=slew -global kvm-pit.lost_tick_policy=discard -no-hpet -no-reboot -global PIIX4_PM.disable_s3=1 -global PIIX4_PM.disable_s4=1 -boot strict=on -kernel /var/lib/libvirt/boot/virtinst-vmlinuz.clUcR1 -initrd /var/lib/libvirt/boot/virtinst-initrd.img.rJ2aiS -device ich9-usb-ehci1,id=usb,bus=pci.0,addr=0x5.0x7 -device ich9-usb-uhci1,masterbus=usb.0,firstport=0,bus=pci.0,multifunction=on,addr=0x5 -device ich9-usb-uhci2,masterbus=usb.0,firstport=2,bus=pci.0,addr=0x5.0x1 -device ich9-usb-uhci3,masterbus=usb.0,firstport=4,bus=pci.0,addr=0x5.0x2 -device virtio-serial-pci,id=virtio-serial0,bus=pci.0,addr=0x4 -drive file=/kvms/template-01a.img,if=none,id=drive-virtio-disk0,format=qcow2 -device virtio-blk-pci,scsi=off,bus=pci.0,addr=0x6,drive=drive-virtio-disk0,id=virtio-disk0,bootindex=1 -drive file=/isos/CentOS-7-x86_64-NetInstall-1511.iso,if=none,id=drive-ide0-0-0,readonly=on,format=raw -device ide-cd,bus=ide.0,unit=0,drive=drive-ide0-0-0,id=ide0-0-0 -netdev tap,fd=23,id=hostnet0,vhost=on,vhostfd=24 -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=hostnet0,id=net0,mac=52:54:00:ac:34:39,bus=pci.0,addr=0x3 -chardev pty,id=charserial0 -device isa-serial,chardev=charserial0,id=serial0 -chardev socket,id=charchannel0,path=/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/channel/target/domain-template-01/org.qemu.guest_agent.0,server,nowait -device virtserialport,bus=virtio-serial0.0,nr=1,chardev=charchannel0,id=channel0,name=org.qemu.guest_agent.0 -device usb-tablet,id=input0 -vnc 0.0.0.0:0,password -vga cirrus -device virtio-balloon-pci,id=balloon0,bus=pci.0,addr=0x7 -msg timestamp=on
char device redirected to /dev/pts/1 (label charserial0)
Could not access KVM kernel module: Is a directory
failed to initialize KVM: Is a directory
2016-10-26 15:08:35.469+0000: shutting down
```

OS Info:

```
root ~ $ cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core) 

root ~ $ uname -r
3.10.0-327.36.3.el7.x86_64

root ~ $ lsmod | grep kvm 
kvm_intel             162153  0 
kvm                   525409  1 kvm_intel
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue was caused be naming my server's volume groups 'kvm'.

The following command fixed this:

```
vgrename kvm kvms
```